# Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNUMBER()'

Tags: formula-field

I tryning to bifurcate primary account name using below formula it's working fine in Excel but giving me an error msg

> " Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNUMBER()'."

in Salesforce for formula field.

```
IF(
  ISNUMBER(FIND("-",Primary_Account__c,1)),
  LEFT(Primary_Account__c,FIND("-",Primary_Account__c,1)-1),
  Primary_Account__c
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISNUMBER expects a text parameter. FIND returns a number which is not compatible with ISNUMBER.

you can directly check if the number returned from FIND is > 0 in your logic

```
IF(
  FIND("-",Primary_Account__c,1) > 0,
  LEFT(Primary_Account__c,FIND("-",Primary_Account__c,1)-1),
  Primary_Account__c
)
```